# DMARC failed for some Emails using SendGrid

Tags: c#, azure, email, sendgrid

I am writing a C# application that can send emails using the SendGridClient for .NET.
Everything is set up so far and kept working for a long time.

But since the last days, some emails are no longer forwarded to their target address. GMX and Outlook work, but Gmail does not work. Those addresses are listed as "Blocked" in the SendGrid Activity List because DMARC failed.

I'm sending the mail as following:

```
SendGridClient client = new SendGridClient(sendGridID);     
EmailAddress from = new EmailAddress("xxx@mydomain.com", "My Sender");
EmailAddress to = new EmailAddress(customerEmail, customerName);

var subject = "Account has been created";
var textContent = "Your account has been successfully created";
var htmlContent = "Some Text";

var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, textContent, htmlContent);
await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

I have checked DKIM and SPD, both seem to be okay. I do not really understand what the problem is. I read about misalignment of the email domains because I'm sending from mydomain.com but the mail itself comes then from sendgrid.net. Is this the problem? How do I fix this? I cannot send from sendgrid.net as this is not the source domain in my case. As I am not a SendGrid pro.. is there a way in SendGrid to configure this?

Comment: Have you gone through Sender verification in SendGrid?

Comment: No not yet, because honestly I'm not really into that stuff. ;-) I looked at it, but thats all. Although I guessed it might be something in this direction.

Answer (score -1):

`Blocks` happen when your message was rejected for *a reason related to the message, not the recipient address.* This can happen when your mail server IP address has been added to a deny list, blocked by an ISP, or if the message content is flagged by a filter on the receiving server.

The **“Reason on the Block”** will clarify what the exact reason is. Typically, it’s possible to have your IP address removed from a deny list, and some lists automatically do this after a period of time. Message content can be modified to correct a filtered block.

Moreover, *you can use `Address Whitelisting` to whitelist Gmail domain.* The address whitelist setting whitelists a specified email address or domain for which mail should never be suppressed. For example, you own the domain example.com, and one or more of your recipients use email@example.com addresses, by placing example.com in the address whitelist setting, all bounces, blocks, and unsubscribes logged for that domain will be ignored and sent as if under normal sending conditions.

Mail settings allow you to tell `Twilio SendGrid` specific things to do to every email that you send to your recipients over `Twilio SendGrid`'s [Web API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html) or [SMTP Relay](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/index.html).

**C# code:**

```
string data = @"{
  'enabled': true, 
  'list': [
    'email1@example.com', 
    'example.com'
  ]
}";
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(data);
data = json.ToString();
var response = await client.RequestAsync(method: SendGridClient.Method.PATCH, urlPath: "mail_settings/address_whitelist", requestBody: data);
Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
Console.WriteLine(response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: This is not a valid answer.  Google and other providers are imposing DMARC checks, which is a newer anti-spam protocol.  See this article from sendgrid.

https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041356934-Troubleshooting-Email-Delivery-Failures-due-to-DMARC